# How to navigate to another screen from a function component?

Tags: react-native, navigation

I have a tabBarNavigation and i have a Home component. In the Home component i want to be able to navigate between two different screens. I have a component called ReadButton which when pressed should take me to another screen called 'BookScreen'. Now i have written so my HomeStack component have two screens 'HomeScreen' and 'BookScreen'. My problem is i cant make the 'ReadButton' to navigate to 'BookScreen' when pressed. It says ''Undefined is not an object(evaluating props.navigation.navigate).

```
...//This is in the main class provided by react

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Book: BookScreen,
  },
  config
);
const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({

HomeStack,
LinksStack,
SettingsStack,

});

tabNavigator.path = '';

export default tabNavigator;

...

//Below is the ReadButton class in a seperate file

import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation'

const ReadButton = (props) => {


  const [ReadPressed, setReadPressed] = useState(true)
  const {navigate} = props.navigation.navigate

  if(ReadPressed){
    return(
            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonstyle} onPress={navigate("Home")}>
                <Text style={styles.textstyle}> READ </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity> 
            </View>  
    )
    }
    else {
        return(
            props.book

        )
    }
}


// Another class where i have my <ReadButton>

function BookCover(){
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.bottomFlexItemWhenClicked} onPress= . 
  {() => setBookCoverState(true)}>
           <Text style={styles.BackgroundText}>{props.text}</Text>
           <ReadButton book={props.book} navigation={props.navigation}>   
          </ReadButton>
   </TouchableOpacity>)}
   }
    export default withNavigation(ReadButton);
```

Now i have tried putting 'Book: BookScreen' over 'Home: HomeScreen' and then the screen actually shows but i cant navigate between them. What am i missing?

Comment: Have passed navigation object to the `ReadButton` component?

Comment: No.. thats all my code for ReadButton. How do i do that? import the navigation object in ReadButton component?

Comment: pass the navigation object to it as a prop

Comment: - About the syntaxe instead of ```const { navigate } = props.navigation.navigate```
you should use ```const { navigate } = props.navigation```

- Please in which class (or component) is the function BookCover() ?

Comment: BookCover is in BooksOnDisplay! but its a whole mess, i think it would be easier with just using a modal right?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try hooks?

1. install hooks: `yarn add react-navigation-hooks@alpha`
2. and then use it in your function component:

```js
import { useNavigation } from 'react-navigation-hooks'

export default function Screen1 () {
  const { navigate } = useNavigation()

  return (
    <Button
      title='Try'
      onPress={() => { navigate('Screen2') }}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: I cant even manage to install it hahah.. it says command not found: yarn

Comment: You can try `npm install react-navigation-hooks@alpha --save`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that components inside the HomeScreen or BookScreen won't receive the navigation prop.

1.Either you send them manually like this

```
<ReadButton navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

or

2.Use the built in withNavigation of react-navigation like this

```
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation'
const ReadButton=(props)=>{}//Now you can access navigation prop here
export default withNavigation(ReadButton)
```

Second method will come to handy when your component is deeply nested and you want to access the navigation prop without manually passing the props.

Comment: i have tried your first method, if i understood it correctly and have updated the code upstairs. Still not working, im guessing i did not understand what you meant correctly..

Comment: If i understood correctly you have a ReadButton inside HomeScreen and this HomeScreen must be receiving navigation as a prop which you can use in the HomeScreen component directly and to use navigation in ReadButton as this.props.navigation, you have to pass the navigation prop to this component inside HomeScreen

Comment: Ahh no, they are in seperate files. HomeScreen, ReadButton are in seperate files. HomeScreen and BookScreen are seperate files also but they are both in my HomeStack but ReadButton is somewhere else. ReadButton is in BookCover which is in BooksOnDisplay which is in BottomFlex which finally is in HomeScreen.  Do i have to pass data through all these to be able to navigate?

Comment: Better to use the second method using withNavigation

Comment: Okay im going to try that now!